# looping through object on auto hot key

Tags: loops, autohotkey

How do I loop through each of these colors so that when I press ctr j the first time it shows up "red" the second time "blue" etc. 
This is what I have so far

```
^j::
colors := Object("red","blue","green", "black")
for key, in colors
    s .= key 
Send, % s
Return
```

However, when I run it the output I get is

```
greenredgreenredgreenredgreenredgreenred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; Creating an array: 
colors := ["red","blue","green","black"]
; or: 
; colors := Array("red","blue","green", "black")

;  MaxIndex returns the number of items: 
MaxIndex := colors.MaxIndex()

^j::
    Index++ ; increases the number in the variable "Index" by 1, each time you press ^j.
    Send, % colors[Index]
    If (Index = MaxIndex)
        Index = 0 ; reset
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Simple_Arrays